# C# codes for Update Mysql Not updating any rows

Tags: c#, mysql

> 1. Here is my code for updating mysql.
> 2. when i execute this,it returns `true`
>    meaning there is one row affected.
> 3. but when i refresh my table, nothing changes.

```
private MySqlCommand cmd;
    
private MySqlConnection conn;

public bool updateBusinessEstablishment(string business_id)
    {

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE bplo_gov_table set " +
                "trade_name=@trade_name, nature_of_business = @nature_of_business where business_id = @business_id "; 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trade_name", this.Trade_name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nature_of_business", this.Nature_of_business);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@business_id", business_id);
            int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            return a >0;


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.ExceptionMessage = e.Message;
            
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

> 4. cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() returns 1

Comment: Can you show us the table before the update, the values you supplied for Trade_Name, Nature_of_business and business_id and the table after the update?

Comment: Do you have a transaction open you need to commit?

Comment: i found my error, but not in this code posted. i forgot to give a new value to my variables that's why during the sql update, still the old value is being send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return of 1 means 1 row has been updated. It is possible to have 1 row updated with same values as previous so that table remains unchanged. Can you please check the data to make sure updates are happening as you like?

Comment: no sir, still nothing changes within my database.

Answer (score 0):

**i found my error, but not in this code posted.**
i forgot to give a new value to my variables that's why during the sql update, still the old value is being send.

Comment: As this is what SmartCoder already said in his answer, it is not useful to add it as separate answer again. I suggest that you delete this answer and maybe add the information as comment to the accepted answer.